# MYSQL changing value of column when certain time is reached

Tags: python, mysql

I currently have a job scheduler made in python that talks to a mysql database. The scheduler finds any job with the status 0 and run it.

I want add a new column which will be "start_time". So if i want to run a job at 10 o'clock mysql database will pick up on the start_time and when it reaches 10 o'clock it will change the status from 1 to 0.

Does anyone know if this is possible? and if it is how i go about setting this up?

Comment: Why not use MySQL Event mechanism instead of implementing your own scheduler?

Comment: yeah that is something i would want. The scheduler just runs python scripts for the job. I would like the MYSQL to change the status by itself. I will have a  look at mysql event. thanks